# redis-py compiatable with redis-server using docker image redis:5.0.9-alpine

Tags: python, kubernetes, redis, redis-py

we have a Redis-Server running as a stateful set on a K8s server with 3 replicas which is using the docker image `redis:5.0.9-alpine`. This server is running in cluster mode `yes`.

Now we are trying to connect this cluster from the python code using the official Redis python package i.e. https://github.com/redis/redis-py but we are getting the below error:

```
File "/code/./app/client/redisclient.py", line 40, in create_redis_cluster_mode
    rc = Redis(startup_nodes=nodes, **{'password':redis_pwd, 'decode_responses':True})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 588, in __init__
    self.nodes_manager = NodesManager(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1330, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/cluster.py", line 1632, in initialize
    self.default_node = self.get_nodes_by_server_type(PRIMARY)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Python code:

```
from redis.cluster import RedisCluster as Redis
from redis.cluster import ClusterNode

def create_redis_cluster():
    nodes = [ClusterNode(redis_host, redis_port, server_type= 'primary')]
    rc = Redis(startup_nodes=nodes, **{'password':redis_pwd, 'decode_responses':True})
```

Initially, we were using the latest Redis package version but we downgraded to 4.1.0 but still got the same error.

Note: `redis:5.0.9-alpine` is 2 years old docker image deployed and we cannot move to the latest version as we have lot of dependencies around it.

---

**the new finding:** I have exec into all the 3 pods of Redis statefulset and upon issuing cluster info command it is showing `cluster_state: fail`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> cluster info
cluster_state:fail
cluster_slots_assigned:0
cluster_slots_ok:0
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:1
cluster_size:0
cluster_current_epoch:0
cluster_my_epoch:0
cluster_stats_messages_sent:0
cluster_stats_messages_received:0
127.0.0.1:6379> cluster nodes
7ddd7d8ce5352db7b3d1f168b4c7db94535d6b2e :6379@16379 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected
```

anyway fixing this would be a great help!!